# Find out where stored proc is called from - [Oracle]

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

How can I find out where my stored procedure `FOO` is called from (names of calling procedures)?
I'm trying to find out in what type of situations `FOO` is called, and it seems very cumbersome to query `SELECT * FROM user_source` because there are string literals that contain `FOO`.

Regards,
Robotron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` view:

```
select * from all_dependencies 
where referenced_owner = <username>
and referenced_name = 'FOO';
```

This will return all objects that directly use your procedure `FOO`. If a procedure uses `FOO` inside a dynamic SQL statement, however, you'll either have to parse the source, or you could try adding logging the call stack inside your `FOO` procedure (in a real application, this would be logged to a table instead of `dbms_output`):

```
create or replace procedure foo as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('foo');
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_call_stack());
  end;

create procedure bar as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('bar');
  foo();
end;  

begin
  bar();
end;
```

Output:

```
bar
foo
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
00000003E180A118         4  procedure SCHMITT.FOO
00000003E180E140         4  procedure SCHMITT.BAR
00000003E17FA388         2  anonymous block
```

However, this will only work if the code that's using your function is actually called :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get this information at runtime, try [`OWA_UTIL.WHO_CALLED_ME`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/w_util.htm#i997852):

```
OWA_UTIL.WHO_CALLED_ME(
   owner          OUT      VARCHAR2,
   name           OUT      VARCHAR2,
   lineno         OUT      NUMBER,
   caller_t       OUT      VARCHAR2);
```

---

If this procedure does not exist, have a look at this post from Tom Kyte:
[How Can I find out who called me or what my name is](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.at/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkytewhocalledme.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this is not what I'm looking for. This would entail me knowing a certain use case, which is not the case here, I'm still trying to figure out what is happening in the system. I have no idea how to even call the calling functions :)